# Bash script backup full MySQL

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, backup

The next script apparently executes successfully cause I get the backup but when I modify some parameters for checking the output of mysqldump all time send an email with the messages "El respaldo diario de la base de datos se ha realizado correctamente" (the backup executed successfully)

```
`#!/bin/bash -x
SERVIDOR="$(hostname)"
PASSWORD='PASSWORD'
FECHA=`/bin/date +\%Y\%m\%d`
NOTIFICADOS=notificados@hotmail.com
STATUSFILE="/tmp/statusfile.$FECHA"

echo "Backup report from $FECHA" > $STATUSFILE
mysqldump  --databases prueba --no-tablespaces --skip-comments --single-transaction --default-character-set=UTF8 --insert-ignore --complete-insert  --add-locks --triggers --routines --events --disable-keys --lock-tables=false --set-gtid-purged=OFF --user=backup -p$PASSWORD > /tmp/$SERVIDOR-DBFLBASEPRUEBA-$FECHA.sql
echo "Muestra la salida de mysqldump: $?" >> $STATUSFILE

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
   echo "El respaldo diario de la base de datos "prueba" en el $SERVIDOR se ha realizado correctamente" >> $STATUSFILE
  else
   echo "El respaldo diario de la base de datos "prueba" en el $SERVIDOR no se ha realizado correctamente" >> $STATUSFILE
  fi

gzip -9 /tmp/$SERVIDOR-DBFLBASEPRUEBA-$FECHA.sql`
```

I executed the script with --no-tablespace the value of mysqldump is 2 but the message said that the backup executed successfully. Can you help me about the correct way to detect an issue, please?

[image]

[image]

Comment: `Dumping structure and contents of MySQL databases and tables.
Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables]`
Try to do this
`mysqldump  --no-tablespaces --skip-comments --single-transaction --default-character-set=UTF8 --insert-ignore --complete-insert  --add-locks --triggers --routines --events --disable-keys --lock-tables=false --set-gtid-purged=OFF --user=backup -p$PASSWORD prueba`

Comment: Your `$?` is result of `echo` command, then will always be `0` !! You have to store them in a variable if you plan to use them many time: `dumpRes=$?`!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what 'F. Hauri` said in the comments above.

```
#!/bin/bash -x
SERVIDOR="$(hostname)"
PASSWORD='PASSWORD'
FECHA=$(/bin/date +\%Y\%m\%d)
NOTIFICADOS=notificados@hotmail.com
STATUSFILE="/tmp/statusfile.$FECHA"

echo "Backup report from $FECHA" > "$STATUSFILE"
mysqldump  --databases prueba --no-tablespaces --skip-comments --single-transaction --default-character-set=UTF8 --insert-ignore --complete-insert  --add-locks --triggers --routines --events --disable-keys --lock-tables=false --set-gtid-purged=OFF --user=backup -p$PASSWORD > /tmp/"$SERVIDOR"-DBFLBASEPRUEBA-"$FECHA".sql
RESULTADO=$?
echo "Muestra la salida de mysqldump: ${RESULTADO}" >> "$STATUSFILE"

if [ ${RESULTADO} -eq 0 ]
then
   echo "El respaldo diario de la base de datos 'prueba' en el $SERVIDOR se ha realizado correctamente" >> "$STATUSFILE"
else
   echo "El respaldo diario de la base de datos 'prueba' en el $SERVIDOR no se ha realizado correctamente" >> "$STATUSFILE"
fi
gzip -9 /tmp/"$SERVIDOR"-DBFLBASEPRUEBA-"$FECHA".sql
```

Added a few more smaller cleanups, and you don't seem to use `$NOTIFICADOS` anywhere.